# reading values from file, line by line in c

Tags: c, scanf, fopen, fgets

I have to open and read a .dat-file with sensorvalues. Every line has a new value I have to read, like:

```
timestamp, value
000000001, 1.233
000000002, 1.345
...
```

I have to write a function which returns everytime i call it a new sensorvalue.
I know how to read whole files, put I dont know how to implement something like a linepointer (who tells me which line to read next) or something like that. 
The timestamps are NOT regulary, so I think i cant use them to get the newest value.

Hope you understand my problem and can help me, thanks!

Comment: `fscanf()`  might become your friend?

Comment: Tons of examples on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the file is read only when you need to read a line, there's nothing extra you must do. Just write a function that reads a line and gives you the data you need. The next time you need to get some sensor data, just call that function again, the internals of `FILE` will do the rest, as it remembers where it was.

   ```
   sensor_data read_data(FILE * fp) {
       ...
       fgets(..., ..., fp);
       /* test */

       /* parse line */
       return sensor_data;
   }
   ```
2. If you do need to move through the file for another reason and the you want to get the line corresponding to the next one, you can either save the file pointer position with `ftell()` and the `fseek()`, or (if you know which line you need), just `fseek(fp, LINE_LENGTH * n, SEEK_SET)`.

   ```
   sensor_data read_data(FILE * fp, long n) {
       ...
       fseek(fp, n * LINE_LENGTH, SEEK_SET);
       fgets(..., ..., fp);
       /* test */

       /* parse line */
       return sensor_data;
   }
   ```